# Installing Ganache.appx on Windows 7

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I have downloaded the Ganache.appx from the official site.

Not sure how to start the ganache blockchain .

When I double click the the file it asks me to choose like below ?

Note : I am having a windows 7 machine . 
I dont find any files in ganache official site for specific version of windows.

[image]

Please let me know how to launch ganache block chain in windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 5):

For Windows 7 dont download from homepage. Please click on other OS link below and there you will get direct exe. It worked for me

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ganache builds are targeted for Windows App Store. Build line should be tweaked to achieve this. Please refer [Ganache Issues](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/issues/221)

Answer (score 0):

Extract this file (Ganache-1.2.2.appx) with 7-zip and you will find (~\Ganache-1.2.2\app\Ganache.exe ) file. run
no need to install